# Unable to install Python 3.8.5 using pyenv

Tags: python, ssl, centos, centos6, pyenv

I'm trying to install Python 3.8.5 using pyenv on Centos 6 Docker image. I am getting the below error:

> Downloading Python-3.6.12.tar.xz...
> -> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.12/Python-3.6.12.tar.xz Installing Python-3.6.12...
>
> BUILD FAILED (CentOS release 6.10 (Final) using python-build
> 1.2.22-47-g4c302a0)
>
> Inspect or clean up the working tree at
> /tmp/python-build.20210131203049.150 Results logged to
> /tmp/python-build.20210131203049.150.log
>
> Last 10 log lines: checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
> checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes checking if g++ supports
> -c -o file.o... (cached) yes checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes checking
> dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so checking
> how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate checking size
> of size_t... 8 checking for C compiler vendor... gcc -pthread -shared
> -L/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.12/lib -L/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.12/lib -L/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.12/lib -I/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.12/include build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tmp/python-build.20210131203049.150/Python-3.6.12/Modules/pyexpat.o
> build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tmp/python-build.20210131203049.150/Python-3.6.12/Modules/expat/xmlparse.o
> build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tmp/python-build.20210131203049.150/Python-3.6.12/Modules/expat/xmlrole.o
> build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tmp/python-build.20210131203049.150/Python-3.6.12/Modules/expat/xmltok.o
> -L/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.12/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/pyexpat.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> /bin/sh: line 9:  8442 Killed                  CC='gcc -pthread'
> LDSHARED='gcc -pthread -shared -L/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.12/lib
> -L/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.12/lib   ' OPT='-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall' _TCLTK_INCLUDES='' _TCLTK_LIBS='' ./python -E ./setup.py $quiet build make: *** [sharedmods] Error 137

Comment: How about this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547335/ssl-needed-for-python-3-8-on-rhel-6

Comment: Updated question with different error.

Comment: You should only edit to add clarification, details, answer commun comments.  Users that have already read your question are not likely to come back to it "in case" you changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a dep. Try this:

```
$ sudo yum install openssl-devel
```

If that's not enough, several other relevant deps are mentioned on https://joshspicer.com/python37-ssl-issue

Notice that merely having openssl installed
is not sufficient.

You need the `-devel` form of the package.
It contains essential ingredients, such as `*.h` header files,
that are necessary for the build to succeed.

---

Use `$ yum list installed` to see what you have ATM.
You might find e.g. `yum list installed | grep -i openssl` convenient.